# Shall we consider automating application if it is no longer going to get updates

Tags: automation, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

We have an application in production and there are slim chances that it would get enhanced further. We are curious whether shall we consider automating same. if yes, how it would be beneficial. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to answer yourself if automation will benefit you. If you don't see benefits from automation - there is none, other than gathering knowledge and experience while developing automation.
Other non-straight benefits:
- robust smoke tests (if update finally comes)
- automated tests are sort of behavior documentation (take a look at BDD)

Making test-automation have positive ROI is probably the hardest step in whole automation. Without experience on what to automate and how to do it, it's negative in most cases. So gathering such knowledge and experience is benefit, which of course comes with a cost. If you have a gut feeling that this case won't benefit you - it probably won't, and you should look for a different place to gather experience.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Automation is always a hot topic in our office. I agree with G. Swiec that ROI is going to be your biggest concern. I personally think there is value in having a robust automation suite for an app. Even if you don't plan on enhancing your app further, the tests could help catch bugs you missed or even if dependencies go wonky. If you have decent tools and the hours to do it, I think it could add value. However, these benefits are quickly outweighed if you don't have the man hours to research and implement an automated testing strategy.

You may want to consider other popular avenues like contract testing. Good contract testing can help relieve the need to write big automated e2e tests altogether!